# static navbar shakes horizontaly on leaving modal

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal, lightbox

currently I have troubles with bootstrap5 and modal respectively glightbox.

- when switching back from these applications, the static navbar shakes horizontaly.
- the same with glightbox, additional to that the sticky footer also slides up when the screen is grayed out.

deliberate specific features: sticky footer, vertical scrollbar always on

```
fullscreen sample: https://codepen.io/manu_g/full/dyZOdbV
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspecting your codepen, I observed that the `margin-left` and `margin-right` of the child element of the `#header` increases, when the modal opens.

When you leave modal, `margin-left` and `margin-right` are returning back to their initial values, causing the shake.

The fixed position seems to be the root of cause. Thus, I would go with `position: sticky` instead and add some margin top in the `.inner-pages`.

For example,

```
.fixed-top {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
}

.inner-page {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: `position: sticky;` solved the shaky header problem - see updated codepen. Do you have a solution for the sliding footer also?

Comment: FIO - solved the sliding footer problem. modify the glightbox.css and remark following statement:    `@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .glightbox-open {
    /* height: auto; */
  }
}`